# how to map an Object.keys array inside an Object.keys in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I try:

```
{Object.keys(questions).map(
    (question, index) => (
        <div className="row questions" key={index}> 
            <p>{questions[question].question_title}</p>
        
         // HERE NOT WORK
         {Object.keys(questions[question].answers).map(
          (answer, index) => (
              console.log(questions[question].answers[answer].id_answer)
          )
         )}

         </div>
    )
)}
```

this return *"Cannot convert undefined or null to object"*

Comment: hi, perhaps step through with a debugger or log `questions` to check if it contains the expected values

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I found the problem, I will update the question, there are some arrays that do not contain this field.

Comment: how do I do an (answers! == "undefined") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this error indicates that you have question(s) where `answers` property is `undefined` or `null`. This results in a call `Object.keys(undefined)` which throws the error.

you need to add a safe guard for your code to not execute if that's the case:

```
     { questions[question].answers && Object.keys(questions[question].answers).map(
      (answer, index) => (
          console.log(questions[question].answers[answer].id_answer)
      )
     )}
```

Comment: @IsaquePalmieri you are welcome! if you feel that answer your question you could consider to mark as accepted answer.